# JSON.NET causes System.TypeAccessException in Dynamics CRM

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I get the below error when running a custom workflow action that uses `JSON.NET` to serialize a dynamics object to JSON.

Is there a restriction on using reflection in CRM Dynamics customer workflow activities / plugins?

Is it because I am using `dynamic` variables?

> System.TypeAccessException: Attempt by method
>   'DynamicClass.CallSite.Target(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, System.Object,
>   System.String)' to access type
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject+JObjectDynamicProxy' failed.    at
>   CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String )    at
>   WSWA.CRM.Logic.MyobIntegrationLogic.CreateInvoice(Boolean retry)    at
>   WSWA.CRM.Workflows.MyobJob.MyobIntegrationTester.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context)

```
        dynamic account = new JObject();
        account.UID = GetAccount("Undeposited Funds Account");

        dynamic job = new JObject();
        job.UID = GetJob("JFC Interiors");

        dynamic gstTaxCode = new JObject();
        gstTaxCode.UID = GetTaxUidByCode("GST");

        dynamic customer = new JObject();
        customer.UID = GetCustomerUid("Bar001.test");

        dynamic line1 = new JObject();
        line1.Total = 22.55;
        line1.Account = account;
        line1.Job = job;
        line1.TaxCode = gstTaxCode;

        dynamic line2 = new JObject();
        line1.Total = 23.55;
        line1.Account = account;
        line1.Job = job;
        line1.TaxCode = gstTaxCode;

        var lines = new JArray();
        lines.Add(line1);
        lines.Add(line2);

        dynamic invoice = new JObject();
        invoice.Date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        invoice.Customer = customer;
        invoice.CustomerPurchaseOrderNumber = "PO Number";
        invoice.Number = "INV-1000";
        invoice.Lines = lines;

        var content = new StringContent(contact.ToString());
        content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/json");

        var responseTask = httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);

        Task.WaitAll(responseTask);
```

Comment: http://www.crmanswers.net/2015/02/json-and-crm-sandbox-plugins.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are known issues with dynamic types and using NuGet packages like Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.

Could you try with a WebClient?

More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334752.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `dynamic` types in Dynamics (ironic isn't it?) CRM Sandboxed plugins.  You can use reflection, as long as whatever you're reflecting is publicly available.  i.e. You can use reflection to get a list of public properties, but you can't get a list of private fields.

You can always farm your work out to an Azure service and do whatever you'd like there.

Comment: Thanks, I just created a class instead of using dynamic.